# Python: How to make this color thresholding function more efficient

Tags: python, performance, opencv, numpy, image-processing

I wrote an adaptive color thresholding function in Python (because OpenCV's cv2.adaptiveThreshold didn't fit my needs) and it is way too slow. I've made it as efficient as I can, but it still takes almost 500 ms on a 1280x720 image.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions that will make this function more efficient!

Here's what the function does: It uses a cross-shape of one-pixel thickness as the structuring element. For each pixel in the image, it computes the average values of `ksize` adjacent pixels in four directions **independently** (i.e. the average of `ksize` pixels in the same row to the left, in the same column above, in the same row to the right, and in the same column below). I end with four average values, one for each direction. A pixel only meets the threshold criterion if it is brighter than either both the left AND right averages or both the top AND bottom averages (plus some constant `C`).

I compute those averages incrementally for all pixels at the same time using `numpy.roll()`, but I still need to do this `ksize` times. The `ksize` will usually be 20-50.

Here is the code, the relevant part is really just what happens inside the for-loop:

```
def bilateral_adaptive_threshold(img, ksize=20, C=0, mode='floor', true_value=255, false_value=0):

    mask = np.full(img.shape, false_value, dtype=np.int16)

    left_thresh = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.float32) #Store the right-side average of each pixel here
    right_thresh = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.float32) #Store the left-side average of each pixel here
    up_thresh = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.float32) #Store the top-side average of each pixel here
    down_thresh = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.float32) #Store the bottom-side average of each pixel here

    for i in range(1, ksize+1): 
        roll_left = np.roll(img, -i, axis=1)
        roll_right = np.roll(img, i, axis=1)
        roll_up = np.roll(img, -i, axis=0)
        roll_down = np.roll(img, i, axis=0)

        roll_left[:,-i:] = 0
        roll_right[:,:i] = 0
        roll_up[-i:,:] = 0
        roll_down[:i,:] = 0

        left_thresh += roll_right
        right_thresh += roll_left
        up_thresh += roll_down
        down_thresh += roll_up

    left_thresh /= ksize
    right_thresh /= ksize
    up_thresh /= ksize
    down_thresh /= ksize

    if mode == 'floor':
        mask[((img > left_thresh+C) & (img > right_thresh+C)) | ((img > up_thresh+C) & (img > down_thresh+C))] = true_value
    elif mode == 'ceil':
        mask[((img < left_thresh-C) & (img < right_thresh-C)) | ((img < up_thresh-C) & (img < down_thresh-C))] = true_value
    else: raise ValueError("Unexpected mode value. Expected value is 'floor' or 'ceil'.")

    return mask
```

Comment: Consider trying this on [Codereview.SE]

Comment: First of all, You can never get efficiency by writing code in Python. If Possible write your logic in C++, it will work 5x faster trust me, If you want to optimise further then you may take help of OpenCV Parallel module `cv::parallel_for()` to run your code parallely

Comment: Thanks @JETM, I've just posted my question there!

Comment: @Zdar I would write the whole thing in C++ in a heartbeat if I could, but I don't know C++ :/. So for now I have to figure out if there are ways to make this more efficient in plain python. Or is that maybe not worth trying, because, how good can it get anyway? :/

Comment: I am telling you this with my experience, Because The Opencv Python API is using C++ internally, And in it would be much faster if you iterate the image in C++ itself.

Comment: Rather than rolling and zeroing out the edges, can you just add up progressively smaller ROIs (with appropriate offsets)?

Comment: Basically make the loop just `for i in range(1, ksize+1): left_thresh[:,i:] += img[:,:w-i];    right_thresh[:,:w-i] += img[:,i:];    up_thresh[i:,:] += img[:h-i,:];   down_thresh[:h-i,:] += img[i:,:]` -- That seems to shave off about 30-40% here.

Comment: Further improvement in obtaining the sums you need to calculate the average would be using 4x `cv2.filter2D` with single row/column kernels and appropriate anchors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you hint in your question, the dominant part of the function is obtaining the 4 arrays of sums needed to calculate the averages -- here it's on average 190ms out of 210ms for the whole function. So, let's focus on that.

First, necessary imports and a convenience timing function.

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import numpy as np
import cv2

## ===========================================================================

def time_fn(fn, img, ksize=20, iters=16):
    start = timer()
    for i in range(iters):
        fn(img, ksize)
    end = timer()
    return ((end - start) / iters) * 1000

## ===========================================================================
# Our test image
img = np.uint8(np.random.random((720,1280)) * 256)
```

### Original Implementation

We can reduce your function in the following manner, so that it just calculates and returns the 4 arrays of sums. We can later use this to check that the optimized versions return the same result.

```
# Original code
def windowed_sum_v1(img, ksize=20):
    left_thresh = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.float32)
    right_thresh = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.float32)
    up_thresh = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.float32)
    down_thresh = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.float32)

    for i in range(1, ksize+1): 
        roll_left = np.roll(img, -i, axis=1)
        roll_right = np.roll(img, i, axis=1)
        roll_up = np.roll(img, -i, axis=0)
        roll_down = np.roll(img, i, axis=0)

        roll_left[:,-i:] = 0
        roll_right[:,:i] = 0
        roll_up[-i:,:] = 0
        roll_down[:i,:] = 0

        left_thresh += roll_right
        right_thresh += roll_left
        up_thresh += roll_down
        down_thresh += roll_up

    return (left_thresh, right_thresh, up_thresh, down_thresh)
```

Now we can find how much time this function takes on local machine:

```
>>> print "V1: %f ms" % time_fn(windowed_sum_v1, img, 20, 16)
V1: 188.572077 ms
```

### Improvement #1

`numpy.roll` is bound to involve some overhead, but there's no need to dig into that here. Notice that after your roll the array, you zero out the rows or columns that spilled across the edge of the array. Then you add this to the accumulator. Adding a zero doesn't change the result, so we may as well avoid that. Instead, we can just add progressive smaller and appropriately offset slices of the whole array, avoiding the `roll` and (somewhat) reducing the total number of additions needed.

```
# Summing up ROIs
def windowed_sum_v2(img, ksize=20):
    h,w=(img.shape[0], img.shape[1])

    left_thresh = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.float32)
    right_thresh = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.float32)
    up_thresh = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.float32)
    down_thresh = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.float32)

    for i in range(1, ksize+1): 
        left_thresh[:,i:] += img[:,:w-i]
        right_thresh[:,:w-i] += img[:,i:]
        up_thresh[i:,:] += img[:h-i,:]
        down_thresh[:h-i,:] += img[i:,:]

    return (left_thresh, right_thresh, up_thresh, down_thresh)
```

Let's test this and time it:

```
>>> print "Results equal (V1 vs V2): %s" % (np.array_equal(windowed_sum_v1(img), windowed_sum_v2(img)))
Results equal (V1 vs V2): True
>>> print "V2: %f ms" % time_fn(windowed_sum_v2, img, 20, 16)
V2: 110.861794 ms
```

This implementation takes only 60% of the time of taken by the original. Can we do better?

### Improvement #2

We still have a loop there. It would be nice if we could replace the repeated additions by a single call to some optimized function. One such function is [`cv2.filter2D`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d), which calculates the following:

[image: filter2D]

We can create a kernel, such that the points we want to add have a weight of `1.0` and the point that the kernel is anchored on has a weight of `0.0`.

For example, when `ksize=8`, we could use the following kernels and anchor positions.

[image: Kernels for ksize=8]

The function would then be as follows:

```
# Using filter2d
def windowed_sum_v3(img, ksize=20):
    kernel_l = np.array([[1.0] * (ksize) + [0.0]])
    kernel_r = np.array([[0.0] + [1.0] * (ksize)])
    kernel_u = np.array([[1.0]] * (ksize) + [[0.0]])
    kernel_d = np.array([[0.0]] + [[1.0]] * (ksize))

    left_thresh = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_32F, kernel_l, anchor=(ksize,0), borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    right_thresh = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_32F, kernel_r, anchor=(0,0), borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    up_thresh = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_32F, kernel_u, anchor=(0,ksize), borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    down_thresh = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_32F, kernel_d, anchor=(0,0), borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)

    return (left_thresh, right_thresh, up_thresh, down_thresh)
```

Again, let's test time this function:

```
>>> print "Results equal (V1 vs V3): %s" % (np.array_equal(windowed_sum_v1(img), windowed_sum_v3(img)))
Results equal (V1 vs V3): True
>>> print "V2: %f ms" % time_fn(windowed_sum_v3, img, 20, 16)
V3: 46.652996 ms
```

We're down to 25% of the original time.

### Improvement #3

We're working in floating point, but right now we don't do any divisions, and the kernel contains only ones and zeros. That means we could potentially work with integers. You mention the maximum window size is 50, which means we're safe with 16 bit signed integers. Integer math tends to be faster, and if the code we use is properly vectorized, we can potentially process twice at once. Let's give this a shot, and let's also provide a wrapper that returns the result in floating point format as the previous versions.

```
# Integer only
def windowed_sum_v4(img, ksize=20):
    kernel_l = np.array([[1] * (ksize) + [0]], dtype=np.int16)
    kernel_r = np.array([[0] + [1] * (ksize)], dtype=np.int16)
    kernel_u = np.array([[1]] * (ksize) + [[0]], dtype=np.int16)
    kernel_d = np.array([[0]] + [[1]] * (ksize), dtype=np.int16)

    left_thresh = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_16S, kernel_l, anchor=(ksize,0), borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    right_thresh = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_16S, kernel_r, anchor=(0,0), borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    up_thresh = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_16S, kernel_u, anchor=(0,ksize), borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    down_thresh = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_16S, kernel_d, anchor=(0,0), borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)

    return (left_thresh, right_thresh, up_thresh, down_thresh)

# Integer only, but returning floats    
def windowed_sum_v5(img, ksize=20):
    result = windowed_sum_v4(img, ksize)
    return map(np.float32,result)
```

Let's test this out.

```
>>> print "Results equal (V1 vs V4): %s" % (np.array_equal(windowed_sum_v1(img), windowed_sum_v4(img)))
Results equal (V1 vs V4): True
>>> print "Results equal (V1 vs V5): %s" % (np.array_equal(windowed_sum_v1(img), windowed_sum_v5(img)))
Results equal (V1 vs V5): True
>>> print "V4: %f ms" % time_fn(windowed_sum_v4, img, 20, 16)
V4: 14.712223 ms
>>> print "V5: %f ms" % time_fn(windowed_sum_v5, img, 20, 16)
V5: 20.859744 ms
```

We're down to 7% if we're fine with 16 bit integers, or to 10% if we want floats.

### Further Improvements

Let's get back to the full thresholding function you wrote. Instead of dividing the sums as a separate step to obtain the average, we can scale the kernels such that `filter2D` returns the mean directly. This is only a small improvement (~3%).

Similarly, you can replace the addition or subtraction of `C`, by providing an appropriate `delta` for the `filter2D` call. This again shaves off a few percent.

**N.B.**: You might encounter few differences arising due to the limits of floating point representation if you implement the two above-mentioned changes.

Another possibility is to make the comparisons required to determine the mask to be comparisons of matrix vs scalar:

```
input < threshold
input - input < threshold - input
0 < threshold - input
0 < adjusted_threshold            # determined using adjusted kernel
```

We can achieve this by modifying the kernels to subtract the value of anchor pixel scaled by an appropriate weight (`ksize`). With numpy, this seems to make only tiny difference, although the way I understand it, we could potentially save half the reads in that part of the algorithm (while `filter2D` presumably still reads and multiplies the corresponding values, even if the weight is 0).

### Fastest Implementation of the Threshold Function

Taking all that in consideration, we can rewrite your function like this, and get the same result in ~12.5% time as the original:

```
def bilateral_adaptive_threshold5(img, ksize=20, C=0, mode='floor', true_value=255, false_value=0):
    mask = np.full(img.shape, false_value, dtype=np.uint8)

    kernel_l = np.array([[1] * (ksize) + [-ksize]], dtype=np.int16)
    kernel_r = np.array([[-ksize] + [1] * (ksize)], dtype=np.int16)
    kernel_u = np.array([[1]] * (ksize) + [[-ksize]], dtype=np.int16)
    kernel_d = np.array([[-ksize]] + [[1]] * (ksize), dtype=np.int16)

    if mode == 'floor':
        delta = C * ksize
    elif mode == 'ceil':
        delta = -C * ksize
    else: raise ValueError("Unexpected mode value. Expected value is 'floor' or 'ceil'.")

    left_thresh = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_16S, kernel_l, anchor=(ksize,0), delta=delta, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    right_thresh = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_16S, kernel_r, anchor=(0,0), delta=delta, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    up_thresh = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_16S, kernel_u, anchor=(0,ksize), delta=delta, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    down_thresh = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_16S, kernel_d, anchor=(0,0), delta=delta, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)

    if mode == 'floor':
        mask[((0 > left_thresh) & (0 > right_thresh)) | ((0 > up_thresh) & (0 > down_thresh))] = true_value
    elif mode == 'ceil':
        mask[((0 < left_thresh) & (0 < right_thresh)) | ((0 < up_thresh) & (0 < down_thresh))] = true_value

    return mask
```

Comment: You are amazing! I've actually implemented the version with cv2.filter2D after I read your comment to my original post and my implementation looks exactly like yours, which is reassuring :). I can confirm your stated performance improvements: It takes only around 25% of the original time. Incorporating the division and addition directly into the kernel is another great idea! I'll do that, too, even if it saves only a few percent. I can't thank you enough! In hindsight it always seems so obvious that my original implementation using np.roll was so unnecessary... oh well, that's how you learn.

Comment: Seriously, you should get an award for the precision and detail of your response. Even illustrating the anchor position graphically? Jesus, you are so awesome. A simple up-vote doesn't do your response justice.

Comment: @Alex [Quick attempt at porting this to C++](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/954082d891cccf3c6bd248ebb4049197c0d029f7/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp#L1895) gets me to about 9% of the original time. At this point I don't see many opportunities for speeding it up further (other than going overboard and optimizing it by hand with SIMD intrinsics). There would probably be some overhead between Python and C++, so you may as well stick with what's in the answer. The times seem quite reasonable considering the work that has to be done. | Time for me to go to bed. Thanks for fun excercise :)

Comment: Thank you for this textbook-quality answer, amazing! One thing though: I don't quite see how the kernels defined above perform the scaling correctly. Suppose you convolve (correlate) the kernel over a patch of pixels that all have the same value, `a`. Then `kernel_l` would compute the result for the anchor pixel as `ksize * a + (-ksize) * a = 0`, even though the average should be `a`. It would have to be `kernel_l = np.array([[1] * (ksize) + [-ksize+1]], dtype=np.int16)` (note the `+1` at the end), but even then it would only be an approximation to the true average for the general case?

Comment: @Alex It no longer just calculates the average, it also subtracts the input, so that we can later compare with scalar 0. So, in your example, 0 is the expected result. I scale everything by the `ksize` constant in order to eliminate the need for division, allowing us to work only with integers.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see it now: Comparing the average to the anchor value is equivalent to comparing the sum to `ksize` times the anchor value, and comparing the two values is equivalent to comparing their difference to zero. Simple arithmetic, my bad. Thanks you!

Comment: I noted one detail: In the last implementation, `C` needs to be rescaled by `ksize` in order for the computations to be equivalent to the original function.